# get ng-model in $scope variable angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have this html code:

```
<select class="" ng-model="livre_selection" material-select multiple watch>
                <option ng-repeat="livre in livres">{{livre.titre }}</option>
            </select>
```

can I get the "livre_selection" in the controller and put it in a variable inside the controller so that I can use it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can get that.follow the example.check **ng-change** and **ng-click** functions.you can do it by using both or only one function.

```
<html>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="yourCtrl">
    <select  ng-model="livre_selection" ng-change="a();" material-select multiple watch>
    <option ng-repeat="livre in livres">{{livre.titre }}</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="save" ng-click="b();">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('yourCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.livres=[{titre:"a"}]; 
      var selectedValue;

      $scope.a = function(){
        selectedValue = $scope.livre_selection;
      }

      $scope.b = function(){
        alert(selectedValue);
      }
    });   
    </script>      
  </body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, AngularJS has two way data binding. whatever you put in the ng-model will be available in the controller through `$scope` object. 
in your case you can access it by `$scope.livre_selection`

Comment: it worked, however when I put console.log(result) it shows the output twice , why is that ?

Comment: could you please use plunkr and post your code there?

Comment: when I modify the value, in the console it is written twice

Comment: Are you calling your controller twice? This happened to me when I was calling it in the routing template and in the markup itself. Also, this is a different issue than what you posted. Can you mark this as the answer?

Comment: @Jean I'm not sure, why this answer is not marked..The other answer is correct but that is not what you asked in the question

Comment: @WildWidow I marked the other because it is more detailed for future people who wonder how it is done and I couldn't mark both answers because they are both correct, so I upvoted yours and marked the other as the answer

Comment: @Jean The other answer is actually misleading. You don't need to rig up ng-change or ng-click for the two way data binding to work.  By default in Angular, any variable attached to ng-model in the view is automatically available in the $scope object in the controller and vice versa..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$scope.livre_selection = '';
```

Because $scope is basically a map, but more advisable yould be to use upperCase variable naming, like so:

```
$scope.liveReSelection = '';
```

After it, you will be able to access this variable in your controller.

You can read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Answer (score -2):

- Controller

  `$scope.livre_selection = ""; <br>`

  `var localVariable = "";`

  `$scope.changeValue=function(changedVal){ localVariable  = changedVal; }`
- HTML
- Write an ng-change in the html near to the controller. 
  `<select class="" ng-change="changeValue(livre_selection)" ng-model="livre_selection" material-select multiple watch>
              <option ng-repeat="livre in livres">{{livre.titre }}</option>
          </select>`